# Loading custom framework in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use an [external framework](http://www.cybergarage.org/net/upnp/c/index.html) for UPnP browsing on the iPhone. The framework works perfectly on the Mac, But when I copy it to the iPhone app, it wouldn't run even if there's no code using the framework yet.

It gives weird error that I can't understand.

```
[Session started at 2008-10-20 15:32:34 +0200.]
objc[2701]: Class CAAnimationGroup is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CATransition is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CAKeyframeAnimation is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CABasicAnimation is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CAPropertyAnimation is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CAAnimation is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CASlotProxy is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CAContextImpl is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CAContext is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CAFilter is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CALayer is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CAMediaTimingFunction is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CAScrollLayer is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CATransaction is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CATransformLayer is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class CATiledLayer is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.
objc[2701]: Class NSCursor is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore. Using implementation from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore.

[Session started at 2008-10-20 15:32:37 +0200.]
Loading program into debugger…
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-962) (Sat Jul 26 08:14:40 UTC 2008)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-apple-darwin".warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "UIKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreGraphics" (not yet mapped into memory).
Program loaded.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to program: `/Users/danielchong/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/305F04A8-840D-4A1A-ADD8-59CEC674152E/uPnP Browser2.app/uPnP Browser2', process 2701.
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic linking of any kind is not supported on the iPhone. I think the fact you're trying to do dynamic linking is confusing the simulator's careful library loading thingamagig (which if I'm not mistaken it's the source of the errors above).

If the license allows this, link the external UPnP code statically into your app instead.